# Garbage characters printed by vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

run after build, i will get the following result.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

```
printf("hello world!");

return 0;
```

}

I ran it using gcc compile in vscode.
Here is the result.

print result : hello world!%

Why is there a '%'?

Comment: what happens if you do `printf("hello world!\n");` ?

Comment: Oh, the '%' disappears. Output : "hello world!"